# Microsoft Fakes test project could not load assembly

Tags: microsoft-fakes

I have a unit test project in a solution that uses Microsoft fakes, and when I build it get the error below. The DLL that it is complaining about being not able to load is on the disk. I've built with Fusion logging turned on and that indicates that the binding was successful, so now am stuck. Any one else had problems with Fakes?

```
could not load assembly Logging at C:\src\Application\Development\Main Development Branch\Source\Common Library\Logging\bin\Debug\Logging.dll
```

Comment: have you seen if the target framework of the logging assembly is <= those of the product and test dlls?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I also have the same problem with one of my assemblies. According to [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809792/could-not-load-project-assembly-for-microsoft-fakes-generation)
this seems to be a bug which will be *"included in next Visual Studio release"*.

As Gleno correctly added, there is a description for a workaround on the Microsoft Connect website now. Removing the `.messages` from the `FakeAssemblies` folder also worked for me, so this should be working for others as well. You may have to click the `Show All Files` button in your `Solution Explorer` to be able to see the folder.

Please use your account to upvote the bug in Microsoft Connect if you are interested in a fix earlier than the *"next Visual Studio release"*.

Comment: When did this start happening? I just had to do a clean install of 2013 + Update 1.  Before that i had Update 1 running like a champ !?

Comment: @felickz Can't say for sure - within our team we use the same setup (same notebooks, same image with os, same Visual Studio etc.). It happened on my system first, a couple of days later on a colleague's system. Subsequently there were some more affected systems. The number of problems with Visual Studio after 2010 seem to increase rather than decrease, at least in our environment.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a bug in visual studio. What you need to do is to manually remove .messages file in FakeAssemblies folder, which should be inside your project directory. If this persists a workaround could be to add deletion to pre-build events.

Answer (score 0):

Open the project folder in explorer. Go to FakesAssemblies folder. Remove 'messages' file.